# OLTP-Database design

Tags: database

I need help. I have 2 tables Books and Authors

- One book can have multiple Authors
- One Author can write multiple Books

So I designed Mapping/Junction table to maintain this relation

My requirement - I want to get Book ID,Name for the given Author combination.
Say in below example Book 'B3' (103) written by Author A2 & A3. So my input will be 302 & 303 (A2 & A3 id's) and query should give me 103 (book id)

Pl suggest schema changes if require

### Here is the sample code work in SQL Server 2005 and above

```
declare @tbl_Books TABLE (Book_ID INT, Book_Name VARCHAR(500))
declare @tbl_Authors TABLE (Author_ID INT, Author_Name VARCHAR(50))
declare @tbl_Mapping TABLE (Mapping_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Book_ID INT, Author_ID INT)

insert into @tbl_Books VALUES (101,'B1'),(102,'B2'),(103,'B3')
insert into @tbl_Authors VALUES (301,'A1'),(302,'A2'),(303,'A3')
insert into @tbl_Mapping VALUES (101,301),(101,302),(102,301),(102,302),(101,303),(103,302),(103,303)

select * from @tbl_Books
select * from @tbl_Authors
select * from @tbl_Mapping

Table : tbl_Books
==========   
Book_ID Book_Name
101 B1
102 B2
103 B3

Table: tbl_Authors   
===================
Author_ID   Author_name
301 A1
302 A2
303 A3

Table:tbl_Mapping        
==============
Mapping_ID  Book_ID Author_ID
1   101 301
2   101 302
3   102 301
4   102 302
5   102 303
6   103 302
7   103 303
```

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to know about this?  This seems like a good design for this type of problem.

Comment: My requirement - I want to get Book ID,Name for the given Author combination, how can I achieve this by using this schema or need to change the schema design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty but it works:

```sql
SELECT x.book_id, b.book_name 
FROM (SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) AS num FROM tbl_mapping GROUP BY book_id) x  --Get all books with a count of their authors
INNER JOIN (SELECT book_id FROM tbl_mapping WHERE author_id IN (302,303)) y  --Get all books which involve the specified authors
    ON y.book_id = x.book_id
INNER JOIN tbl_books b
    ON b.book_id = x.book_id
WHERE x.num = 2  --Filter for books which have exactly the required number of authors
GROUP BY x.book_id, b.book_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2  --Filter for how many times each book appears in the results. We want those that appear as many times as there are authors being searched
```

To make it less static you would somehow have to get your `IN` clause to be built according to the list of author IDs you supply and where it says `= 2` you would need to change the `2` to the number of authors being search by.

I tested it by adding another book to your example data written by only one author and adjusting the query accordingly. It returned what I expected. Also tried the book with three authors which works too. This hardly constitutes robust testing but it proves the basic concept. I'm certain there's a nicer way to do this possibly using window functions but frankly it's my dinner time and I'm starving so I can't think of it!

Comment: Also, the ID column on the mapping table is pretty surplus to requirements.

Comment: The reason it's such a pain to do is that you want to return only the books written by exactly the two authors you specify and not, say, any book in which they have both had a hand (possibly with others). To be honest whatever design you do, the search will probably be more complex one way than the other. Picking a book and looking for authors is easy, finding books written by an author in whole or part is easy, this is the hard bit. Another design would probably make this easier and one of the other searches harder.

Comment: Yes Steve, I agree with you
Search on Authors combination to get book is hard in this design
Yes, I am looking for a better design for efficient queries

Comment: Well I think you'll probably find that each design you can find will have it's drawbacks for certain searches. The query plan for this isn't actually too bad (SQL Server), but of course you must ensure that you design your indexes appropriately. Use clustered indexes on your primary keys if you are going to be searching on them and NC indexes elsewhere as appropriate. That's a whole other debate though.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for Book ID and Book names for a given set of authors.

You could try something like (very much pseudo-sql):

```
select tb.Book_ID, tb.Book_Name, SUM(tm.Author_ID) as authors FROM tbl_Mapping tm
       INNER JOIN tbl_Book tb on tb.Book_ID = tm.Book_ID
       WHERE tm.Author_ID IN ( <your list of authors>)
       AND authors = (<the number of authors passed in>)
       GROUP BY tb.Book_ID
```

But I'm not sure of the legality of the authors alias as a filter (I've never really done this direclty in SQL)

A programatic approach, however, would be to have a query like:

```
select Book_ID from tbl_Mapping WHERE Author_ID = <One author ID>
```

And put it in a loop.  The above query is the first execution, and later queries also have

```
AND BOOK_ID IN (<List of Book IDs returned by previous loops)
```

you loop until you run out of authors, and then you run those IDs through a query to get the name (or you tack the name on to the previous queries and also track it).

Comment: You cannot have an aggregate in a `WHERE` clause so that will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I am really not sure whether I understood your answer
How we can have an aggregate clause with out GROUP BY?

By intension is not only on query, I really want to know my schema design is good enough to handle this requirement?

Comment: updated things a bit.  I think the schema is good.  If you can't get this exactly to work in one query, you can easily do something programatic in the application to get what you want.

Comment: `COUNT` is an aggregate function and that may not appear in a `WHERE` clause: _An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference_

Comment: That still won't work (at least in SQL Server and probably others too) because `authors` is not a valid column to filter on as you point out. My approach is similar but since I do the count in a subquery it can then be referenced outside as a filter. Other than that it's similar-ish.

Comment: @StevePettifer my approach to SQL is usually to set up a test database and tweak my queries until they work the way I want.  Much harder to do it off the top of my head.  I've never had to do anything with HAVING, which obviously works for this solution as you show.